# Creating Buttons but have each Button have it's own variable name

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have a program where you can press one "stack button" and create 9 stacks (which are just buttons). However, I want it to where each button has it's own identity, so if I click on a specific one, and it will take me to a specific window for each.

Here is my code:

```
private void createButtonActivate(){
    System.out.println("A stack has been created");
    stackCount++;
    newStackButton = new Button((Integer.toString(stackCount)));
    newStackButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        methods.openNoteCard();
    });

    root.getChildren().add(newStackButton);
}
```

Here is what is called to create the Buttons:

```
private void createStack(){
    stackCreated = true;

    if (stackCount < 3 ) {
        createButtonActivate();
        buttonXPos = buttonXPos + 150;
    }
    else if (stackCount >= 3 && stackCount < 6){
        if (stackCount == 3){
            buttonXPos = 50;
            buttonYPos = buttonYPos + 150;
        }
        createButtonActivate();
        buttonXPos = buttonXPos + 150;
       // buttonXPos =
    }
    else if (stackCount >= 6 && stackCount < 9){
        if (stackCount == 6){
            buttonXPos = 50;
            buttonYPos = buttonYPos + 150;
        }
        createButtonActivate();
        buttonXPos = buttonXPos + 150;
    }

}
```

I hope I didn't provide too much code and I actually explained my problem thoroughly haha anyway, thank you for any help!

Comment: "I want it to where each button has it's own identity, so if I click on a specific one, and it will take me to a specific window for each" - it sounds to me like you're mixing up concepts. You want the buttons to have individual actions, but that's not the same thing as needing them to be referred to be individual names. Without a better description of what you want to achieve, it's hard to give any more help. Possibly it's just a matter of adding a parameter to the createButtonActivate method to specify which window the button should associate with?

Comment: I may have explained it poorly but looks like someone understood and helped me out. Thank you though!

Comment: Unrelated Note: Are you sure a `StackPane` is the best layout option here? You may be able to save a lot of work and trouble by using a layout that arranges the buttons for you (instead of trying to lay them out at precise coordinates yourself).

Comment: @Zephyr Absolutely not sure haha I am decently new to it all. What would you recommend? If you have links, I love reading!

Comment: @DannonGilbert - it depends on what you want your final layout to look like. You could use a `FlowPane` if you want to add multiple nodes in a row and have them flow to the next line. Or a `GridPane` if you want them evenly spaced in precise row/column locations. There are a lot of options. Google for JavaFX layouts and take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make buttons with unique logic when they are clicked, you can actually add a parameter to your `openNoteCard` method.

For example:

```
void openNoteCard(int stackId) {
    switch (stackId) {
        case 0: //logic for the first button
        case 1: //logic for the second button
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

So, in your `createButtonActive` method, it will look like this:

```
private void createButtonActivate(){
    System.out.println("A stack has been created");
    stackCount++;
    newStackButton = new Button((Integer.toString(stackCount)));
    newStackButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        methods.openNoteCard(stackCount); // Passing a parameter here
    });

    root.getChildren().add(newStackButton);
}
```

Comment: Whoa!! Thank you. I can't wait to implement this. That helps a lot.